# How to install a decent bug tracker on a Ubuntu server?

Tags: software-recommendation, 14.10

I looked at Bugzilla, but it doesn't seem to have an easy-to-install .deb package.

I tried Trac, but the 2nd step of the install instructions after installing the .deb package fails with some python errors.

```
> mkdir /opt/test/trac
> trac-admin /opt/test/trac/ initenv
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/trac-admin", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('Trac==1.0.1', 'console_scripts', 'trac-admin')()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/trac/admin/console.py", line 567, in run
    translation.activate(locale)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/trac/util/translation.py", line 325, in activate
    translations.activate(locale, env_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/trac/util/translation.py", line 152, in activate
    t.add(Translations.load(locale_dir, locale or 'en_US',
AttributeError: 'NullTranslations' object has no attribute 'add'
```

Is there a standard bug tracking package that can easily be installed on a Ubuntu server?  (Bonus points if it integrates with Subversion.)

---

**Edit:**  From what I read, the Mantis .deb package was out-of-date and had security issues which is why it was removed from the repo. Same reason why the Bugzilla package was removed. I want a bug tracking system which is current with .deb files accessible in a repo (or PPA) so I can get security fixes as issues are found.

Comment: (I don't think it makes much of a difference, but this server is running 14.10, not 14.04 like I initially thought.)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are lucky, I found one. But it doesn't look that easy. I never used it, but it seems to fit your requirements.

It's called [fossil](http://www.fossil-scm.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki)

```
sudo aptitude install fossil
```

I also found a "[top ten](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/08/bug-tracking-system/)" page from a user, which might be of use.

Comment: > sudo apt-get install mantis
E: Unable to locate package mantis

Comment: get into your synaptic and take a look at the package sources, maybe universe isn't active?

Comment: I have multiverse, universe, backports, and partner all enabled.  I don't see a package named mantis anywhere.  (This server is running 14.10, not 14.04 like I first thought.)

Comment: Now u got me baffled. I tried myself and it's not working. But I installed this before, there are even videos on youtube how to install it. o_O

Comment: OH snap! It's not in trusty,  myabe you can get the older version through the backports?

Comment: The problem with manual install from source is that it doesn't scale.  I'll never know when security updates or recommended upgrades are available.

Comment: well that's (not entirely) true, but I get it, it's more work to keep track on the updates.